# How to sum up and other calculations by the other columns in the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT * FROM INVOICE;
```

| id | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 20 |
| 4 | 30 |
| 5 | 100 |
| 6 | 20 |
| 7 | 30 |
| 8 | 100 |

I would like to create three more columns which will be calculated by the amount column.

```
openamt  = Sum of amount
debamt   = Sum of amount where amount < 50
credamt  = Sum of amount where amount > 50
closeamt = openamt - debamt + credamt
```

Expected output:

| id | amount | openamt | debamt | credamt | closeamt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 340 | 140 | 200 | 400 |
| 2 | 20 | 340 | 140 | 200 | 400 |
| 3 | 20 | 340 | 140 | 200 | 400 |
| 4 | 30 | 340 | 140 | 200 | 400 |
| 5 | 100 | 340 | 140 | 200 | 400 |
| 6 | 20 | 340 | 140 | 200 | 400 |
| 7 | 30 | 340 | 140 | 200 | 400 |
| 8 | 100 | 340 | 140 | 200 | 400 |

What I tried, I got it working for `openamt` but not for the rest. Can somebody point out me to the right direction, please?

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    AMOUNT, 
    SUM(AMOUNT) OVER () AS OPENAMT,
    (SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM INVOICE WHERE AMOUNT < 0) AS DEBTAMT,  -- This is how I want
    (SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM INVOICE WHERE AMOUNT > 0) AS CREDAMT,   -- This is how i want
    (OPENAMT - DEBTAMT + CREDAMT) AS CLOSEAMT
FROM 
    INVOICE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were in the right area.  You can use a conditional aggregation within the window function `sum() over()`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([id] int,[amount] int)  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,20)
,(2,20)
,(3,20)
,(4,30)
,(5,100)
,(6,20)
,(7,30)
,(8,100)
 
Select * 
      ,openamt  = sum(amount) over()
      ,debamt   = sum( case when amount<50 then amount end) over()
      ,credamt  = sum( case when amount>=50 then amount end) over()
      ,closeamt = sum(amount) over()
                 -sum( case when amount<50 then amount end) over()
                 +sum( case when amount>=50 then amount end) over()
 From @YourTable
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Ah Great! Thanks a lot John

Comment: You can just remove the `over()`s

Comment: @juergend: **no** - you can't - you'll get *Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 11 - 
Column '@YourTable.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*

Comment: @juergend True, but then you would have to CROSS JOIN the results

Comment: @johncappelletti One more question, I have a group by id column already and cannot change it. Due to this, I got `amount is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause`  -- Any other way?

Comment: @Sri I don't understand.   In your source, are there multiple rows for each ID ?

Comment: @Sri  Here is a modified approach assuming your source needs to be aggregated  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=58481419d988aa34644481653c05063a

Comment: @JOHNCAPPELLETTI Yes, In my source there can be multiple rows of each ID.

Comment: @Sri Got it then take a peek at the dbFiddle in my last comment

Comment: Thanks @johncappelletti

Comment: @Sri Just another option using a CROSS JOIN and no window functions  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a530291634dda28b795bf1a672cc2e55

Comment: Once again, Thank you so much for the answer and the explanations as well.

Answer (score 2):

If the definition of `credamt` includes the `=` sign also like this:

> credamt  = Sum of amount where amount >= 50

then `closeamt` is just twice `closeamt` because obviously:

```
openamt = debamt + credamt
```

so:

```
closeamt = openamt - debamt + credamt
         = (debamt + credamt) - debamt + credamt
         = 2 * credamt
```

Use `SUM()` window function:

```
SELECT *, 
       SUM(amount) OVER() openamt,
       SUM(CASE WHEN amount < 50 THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) OVER() debamt,
       SUM(CASE WHEN amount >= 50 THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) OVER() credamt,
       2 * SUM(CASE WHEN amount >= 50 THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) OVER() closeamt
FROM tablename;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5b9c1b47cabad8c5a82039cd0f2ab25e).

Comment: A couple of decades in Banking and I zoomed right past the 2X   +1

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I don't believe that the names of the columns reflect the actual purpose of the columns. There is no way that a *close amount* would be equal to  2x*debit amount* in any banking system.

Comment: LOL ...  My point was that I didn't see the pattern/math

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I did get your point and I had to reply *don't worry*, the pattern should not even be there.